# laravel 4.2 oauth complications

Tags: php, rest, laravel, oauth

I have written an api for a project that uses, [oauth2](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/tree/1.0) to authenticate users, and lock down that api to only people with an access token, and it works fantastically well, we have a route group that looks like this,

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api', 'before' => 'oauth'), function() {

});
```

The problem I am now facing is that scope of the project has changed and we need to extend the api a little bit. Basically at the moment, the API is used to create projects, and a project a can have a team that can CRUD a project.

The scope has changed now so that a project can also have client user who can follow a unique link to monitor the progress of the project, and update certain aspects of the project.

The problems are 2 fold,

1) You cant do anything on our API without an access token, so even a GET request for data to build the page would be turned down for a client user.

2) To get a access token you need a username and password. The key thing for a client user is that do not need to login, they should be able to just get a unique URL in email, and then load the project.

I figure that creating a custom grant type would be the best solution is that correct? If that is correct does anyone have any guidance on creating one?

If that is not the best way what other options do I have available to me?